# React Native - Drawer Layout is not working

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

Hello I am trying to do create a drawer layout in React Native CLI (Not Expo), but all code I tried or found, even ChatGPT won't work. Here is my last code. Can some help me a tel me what I missed? I don't get the error message "Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type."!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import 'react-native-reanimated';

function HomeScreen({navigation}) { // ERROR HERE
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({navigation}) { // ERROR HERE
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my config in package.json.

> ```
> {
>   "name": "MyApp",
>   "version": "0.0.1",
>   "private": true,
>   "scripts": {
>     "android": "react-native run-android",
>     "ios": "react-native run-ios",
>     "lint": "eslint .",
>     "start": "react-native start",
>     "test": "jest"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
>     "react": "18.2.0",
>     "react-native": "0.73.1",
>     "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
>     "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
>     "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
>     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
>     "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
>     "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
>     "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
>     "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
>     "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
>     "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
>     "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
>     "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
>     "eslint": "^8.19.0",
>     "jest": "^29.6.3",
>     "prettier": "2.8.8",
>     "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
>     "typescript": "5.0.4"
>   },
>   "engines": {
>     "node": ">=18"
>   }
> }
> ```

Here is the error I receive!

[image]

Comment: Just to get rid of the error you could supply any type like so `({navigation}: any)` or to do it properly follow their documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't followed all the required steps

- First of all, complete [these](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) steps to install `react Navigation` properly
- After that, complete [these](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) steps to install `drawer navigation` properly